# ¿Como actualizar el JTextField?

Tags: java, hilos, timer

Hola lo que este codigo hace es basicamente emular el procesamiento por lotes, el codigo ya funciona como necestio, el unico problema es que no se actualiza de manera automatica con cada segundo que pasa, ¿Cómo hacer que se actualice de manera automatica? aqui les dejo el codigo del *timer* que uso

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

/**
 *
 * @author Balam
 */
public class Tiempo {
    public Timer timer = new Timer(); 
    static int segundos=0;
    static int global=0;
    String aux1="";

    //Clase interna que funciona como contador
    class Contador extends TimerTask {
       
        public void run() {
            segundos++;
            global++;
            System.out.println("segundo: " + segundos);
            System.out.println("global: " + global);
        }
    }
    //Crea un timer, inicia segundos a 0 y comienza a contar
    public void Contar()
    {
        this.segundos=0;
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new Contador(), 0, 1000);
    }
    //Detiene el contador
    public void Detener() {
        timer.cancel();
    }
    //Metodo que retorna los segundos transcurridos
    public int getSegundos()
    {
        return this.segundos;
    }
 
        
}
```

Intente poner el siguiente fragmento de codigo para que se actualice

```
Tiempo tiempo = new Tiempo();
Datos datos = new Datos();
String ba="";
String bo="";
if(g<datos.nombre.size()){
ba=String.valueOf(tiempo.global);
bo=String.valueOf(tiempo.segundos);
jTextField12.setText(ba);
jTextField11.setText(bo);
jTextField7.setText(datos.nombre.get(g));
jTextField8.setText(datos.primern.get(g)+datos.simbolo.get(g)+datos.segundon.get(g));
jTextField9.setText(String.valueOf(datos.tiempo.get(g)));
jTextField10.setText(String.valueOf(datos.id.get(g)));
jTextField5.setText(String.valueOf((datos.tiempo.get(g))-(Integer.parseInt(jTextField11.getText()))));
jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(datos.nuevo-(p+1)));
jTextField4.setText(String.valueOf((datos.nuevo)-(Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()))));
jTextField2.setText(String.valueOf(u+1));
jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(datos.totale.get(p)));

if(jTextField5.getText().equals("0")){
    jTable1.setValueAt(datos.id.get(g), g, 0);
    jTable1.setValueAt(jTextField8.getText(), g, 1);
    jTable1.setValueAt(datos.resultado.get(g), g, 2);
    g++;
    u++;
    
    tiempo.segundos=0;
    if(g==4){
        p++;
        u=0;
    }
}

if(jTextField1.getText().equals("0") && jTextField5.getText().equals("0")){
    Tiempo tempo = new Tiempo();
    tempo.Detener();
}
}
```

Este fragmento lo puse en el timer cada segundo que avanzaba, tambien intente ponerlo en el `jframe`, pero ninguna de ambas opciones funciono, lo mas que pude hacer fue que se actualizara cada que presiono el `jtextfield` pero necesito que lo haga de manera automática

Comment: Muestranos que has intentado por favor

Comment: Ya intentaste mandarlo al hilo de pintado (SwingUtilities.invokeLater) ?

Comment: Como se hace eso?

Comment: eso deberia de ponerlo en el timer? o en el JFrame?